# Chrome Developer Tools: Missing "Resources" Tab

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am running **Chrome Version 52.0.2743.116 (64-bit)** on OS X 10.11.3 and upon trying to debug a website realized that the *Resources* tab in my *Developer Tools* is just completely gone. What gives / has anyone else noticed this?

[image: screenshot1]

[image: screenshot2]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between "Resources" and "Application" in Chrome DevTools?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38889921/what-is-the-difference-between-resources-and-application-in-chrome-devtools)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

"The Resources panel has been renamed to the Application panel. All of the features from the Resources panel are still available in the Application panel."

from https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/manage-data/?hl=en

Comment: Why are they renaming it?! This is so confusing.

Comment: And now I can't find the Application panel!